# First Thursday of the month if not passed

Tags: php

In PHP, I need to show the first Thursday of the current month if it's upcoming, or the first Thursday of the next month if the first Thursday of the current month is passed.

I've got this as a starting point:
echo date("F dS", strtotime("first Thursday next month"));

How can I achieve the whole logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$first = strtotime('first thursday this month');
if ($first < time()) {
   // first thursday this month already past, so...
   $first = strtotime('first thursday next month');
}
```

Note that this just a very simple example to demonstrate the logic. `first thursday this month` will come out with a time of midnight on that first thursday. If you run this code at 12:00:01am you'll still detec that "thursday" is past.